# how to get data from sql one by one row

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I will give barcode of item then item data would be fetch into datagridview.

[image]
These Code only fetching one row, if again i fill barcode this code updating row not updating new row. I want to new row

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=QuickBook;Integrated Security=True");
string query = "select productName,productDescription,productUnitPrice from productsInfo where productBarcode =" + p_barcode.Text + "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Are you rebinding the datagridview after getting the new result?  Also, is your SQL statement qualified with apostrophes around the textbox value?

Answer (score 0):

try to check with ' apostrophes

```
string query = "select productName,productDescription,productUnitPrice from productsInfo where productBarcode = '" + p_barcode.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  da.Fill(dt); 

//this loop is pseudocode. Dont remember the exakt syntax
    Foreach(DataRow r in dt) 
    {
        dgvDT. Rows. Add(r. Copy()) 
    } 

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvDT;
```

Make dgvDT a datamember and not local variable